# How do I use $project on joined collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

```js
db.books.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from:'book_copies',
        localField:'ISBN10',
        foreignField:'book_id',
        as:'book_copies'
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

The code above simply make collection `"books"` join collection `"book_copies"`, there are couple repeating value after join such as `"id"` and `"book_id"`.

Content after `$lookup`:
[image: Content after $lookup]

I would like to only keep `branch_id` and `no_of_copies` in book_copies. How do I do that?

```js
db.books.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from:'book_copies',
        localField:'ISBN10',
        foreignField:'book_id',
        as:'book_copies'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        ISBN10:1,
        ISBN13:1,
        Title:1,
        Cover:1,
        Publisher:1,
        Pages:1,
        Authors_arr:1,
        branch_id:1,
        no_of_copies:1
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

My attempt was to set `branch_id` and `no_of_copies` to `1`, but this way just erased all content from `book_copies`.

[image: content after project]
This is what expected to get
[image: Expected]

Comment: i think you need a `$lookup` with pipeline and do the `$project` inside the pipeline see $lookup documentation.

Comment: Please don't use images for code/errors/output/backtraces/etc. - just include the text in a codeblock.

Comment: You don't have a `branch_id` field after the `$lookup`. Instead, you have a `"book_copies.branch_id"` field.  Similarly with `no_of_copies`. Change your `$project` to use the full name and it will probably work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rickhg12hs suggests, please do not paste images. The actual text of the sample documents allows us to test and more appropriately suggest a solution to your problem.

Changing your `$project` to exclude the fields that you don't want should achieve your goals:

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "book_copies._id": 0,
      "book_copies.book_id": 0
    }
  }
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v9sZOZidIra).

Alternatively, you can use [the approach by @Takis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595851/how-do-i-use-project-on-joined-collections-in-mongodb#comment131672729_74595851) to do the `$project` inside of the `$lookup` itself:

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "book_copies",
      localField: "ISBN10",
      foreignField: "book_id",
      as: "book_copies",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            book_id: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hPv7Pb3_Iax).

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Sorry it was my first time to post things on stackoverflow. Still, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solved your question please be sure to accept it as the answer to indicate that the question is resolved